# iOS: adding activity indicator in the right place (Master-View-Controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail, uiactivityindicatorview

I am starting from the MasterViewController / DetailViewController template in XCode. I added a call where I fetch the data from the web (JSON) and will populate the array with it.

**I would like to add an activity indicator in the MasterViewController and show it whilst loading the data.**

However I am unsure on how to proceed with this and **WHERE** I should put it. There are two alternatives I am thinking of:

1. create a custom cell with only one activity indicator in it and show
   only this cell before the data is loaded.
2. add the activity indicator on the view as subview programmatically
   and show it only whilst the data is loading.

Any alternative suggestion? What are the design guidelines by Apple on this?

Here is the project as shown in storybuilder:

[image]

Comment: I think there is no need in subview, in most apps the activity indicator is on the tableview itself (if its not custom and fancy) , also I would pay attention how long take to data to arrive. for instance if u have an image there is a sense to put a placeholde as activity indictor on top of the image but in your case I would use one activity indicator to tableview.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Controls.html all the rest is up to u.

Comment: The UIActivityIndicatorView that you place wherever you like on the Storyboard has two set-able behavior Attributes: "Animating" and "Hides When Stopped". The first is an always-on behavior; the second, however, means you don't have to worry about hiding it when it's done.

Answer (score 0):

It's an indirect answer, but you should take a look at [`MBProgressHUD` on GitHub](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

It is a great class for displaying modal progress views. There's support for:

1. Indeterminate progress views (meaning a spinning activity indicator)
2. Determinate progress views (where you can show actual progress)
3. Labels:

   - LabelText: main text for the HUD
   - DetailsLabelText: a place for detail/message text

In addition, it's easy to style and I've found it much easier than trying to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

For example, here's an easy way to add the HUD to the `view` of a `UIViewController`:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud          = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.detailsLabelText        = @"Loading...";
hud.dimBackground           = YES;
hud.labelText               = @"Please Wait...";
hud.mode                    = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
```

Later, getting rid of it is as easy as:

```
[hud dismiss:YES];
```

> ***Caveat:*** This is not a drop-in replacement for the `UIRefreshControl` that you get with a `UITableViewController`. I'm not sure if it's required, but I always use this view (`MBProgressHUD`) as a blocking control, while something is occurring in the background, such as an asynchronous data load. That said, after my initial data load (when I use an `MBProgressHUD`), I perform subsequent data **refreshes** in the background without interrupting the UI.